# NSTextField not showing it contents until clicked

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have two NSTextField's witch's values are updated when one of them are being edited (it is size, and when editing one of text field, other is being updated constraining proportions). First time when these text fields are shown (it is shown in save panel) both text fields are showing their value, but when one of them is being edited later save panel is opened again, one of text fields are not showing its value till I press mouse on it (select for editing). When mouse is pressed somewhere else (for example on other text field, value gones again. Text field value is automatically edited like that:

```
float _other_text_field_value = [_other_text_field floatValue];
float _aspect_ratio = _image_width/_image_height;
float _new_text_field_value = _other_text_field_value/aspect_ratio;
[_text_field setFloatValue:_new_text_field_value];
```

Image:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did this work for you?
Look at my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an initial check in the awakeFromNib: method.
They are not being loaded, because they are not being edited until then.

**EDIT**

drawRect is no good for this. 
By setting the float value, the textfield has to draw again to show the new value. 
Awake from nib is called when an object is initialised from a nib file. Best for this is to use the NSTextFieldDelegate.
You can set the delegate property of the text fields in Interface Builder.
Look at the following link:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSControlTextEditingDelegate

Comment: I added code like: `[_text_field setFloatValue:_default_float_value];` in `drawRect` method, sow it is done every time when save panel is opened or closed. But result is still the same. `awakeFromNib` method is called only when app launches. And when app launches textfields are working good. It crashes only after editing one of values.

Comment: I'm actually not getting what are you telling me. Text field's value is reseted before every time when save panel is opening. So it has value always and is edited. It is just not showing it